# Android layout help, missing elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gui

I’m trying to creating a layout that contains a "SurfaceView"  at the top with a horizontal toolbar that is section into 3 segments in the bottom, however my SurfaceView which contains camera preview is only the only element that is showing. Please point out the error in my layout xml or provide me the similar layout xml, Thanks.

**Below is my layout & updates based on user recommendations**

**Attempt # 1 (RelativeLayout as root):**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutForPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.68"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is my desired GUI look:

[image]

**Attempt #1 Result , device snapshot , which only shows the SurfaceView:**

[image]

**Snapshot of eclipse GUI tool, which shows what the layout should look like.** 
[image]

**Attempt # 2 (LinearLayout as root):**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutForPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.68"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Attempt #2 , Result , Device snapshot :**

[image]

**Issues:**

1) Toolbar appears on top rather than on bottom

2) Camera preview freezes & app crashes. For some reason LinearLayout causes the Camera error 1001 , and I think its related to preview sizes.

**Attempt #3 (Add toolbar programmatically to either Relative or Linear layout in activity onCreate).**

**LinearLayout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutForPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Toolbar defined in separate XML added later via Java code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--  LinearLayout that contains toolbar that is divided into 3 sections horizontally , layout_below="@+id/BarcodeScannerFrame-->
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.68"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**onCreate,onResume,other relevant code snippets of my activity only, the LinearLayout toolbar is added to Linear or Relative layout at runtime:**

```
//import not included 
    public class ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity extends Activity {
        // camera object that is used globally in this activity and also passed
        // reference to PreviewSurface inner class
        private Camera globalCamera;
        private int cameraId = 0;
        // bitmap that would created after picture is taken and converted from
        // camera bytes
        private Bitmap bmpOfTheImageFromCamera = null;
        // global flag whether a camera has been detected
        private boolean isThereACamera = false;
        // layout for this activity
        private LinearLayout RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner= null;
        // CameraPreview extends SurfaceView displays preview of images from the
        // Camera
        private CameraPreview newCameraPreview = null;
        // used to inflate the xml layout
        private SurfaceView surfaceViewBarcodeScanner = null;
        private boolean cameraPreviewing = false;
        // this continueToAutomaticallyDecode flag is initially set to TRUE, but
        // will be set to FALSE on the first successful decode OR when a crucial
        // method in the code process fails or throws an exception
        private volatile boolean continueToAutomaticallyDecode = true;
        // global flag used to indicate picture taking & decoding is in progress
        private volatile boolean takingPictureAndDecodeInprogress = false;
        // Bitmap options for bitmap creation from camera picture
        BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
        // used for samsung galaxy s devices only
        private Matrix rotationMatrix90CounterClockWise = null;
        // Reader is class from zxing used to decode barcodes
        Reader reader = null;
        // DecodeHintType hashtable is used to provide help to the zxing Reader
        // class
        Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = null;
        //
        private boolean onTouchEvent = true;
        //
        private OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = null;
        // 1 means the screen is PORTRAIT and 2 means screen is LANDSCAPE
        private int latestScreenOrientation = 1;
        //
        Camera.Parameters Flash = null;
        //
        private String globalVIN = null; 
        //
        private Handler handler = null;
        //
        private LinearLayout barcodeVinScannerToolbar = null; 

        public boolean isContinueToAutomaticallyDecode() {

            return continueToAutomaticallyDecode;
        }

        public void setContinueToAutomaticallyDecode(
                boolean continueToAutomaticallyDecode) {

                this.continueToAutomaticallyDecode = continueToAutomaticallyDecode;

        }

        public boolean isTakingPictureAndDecodeInprogress() {
            return takingPictureAndDecodeInprogress;
        }

        public void setTakingPictureAndDecodeInprogress(
                boolean takingPictureAndDecodeInprogress) {

                this.takingPictureAndDecodeInprogress = takingPictureAndDecodeInprogress;

        }

        /*
         * This method , finds FEATURE_CAMERA, opens the camera, set parameters ,
         * add CameraPreview to layout, set camera surface holder, start preview
         */
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        private void initializeGlobalCamera() {

            try {
                if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                        PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else { // check for front camera ,and get the ID
                    cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
                    if (cameraId < 0) {

                        Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                                "camera was found , ID: " + cameraId);
                        // camera was found , set global camera flag to true
                        isThereACamera = true;
                        // OPEN
                        globalCamera = getGlobalCamera(cameraId);
                        // parameters auto focus
                        globalCamera.getParameters().setFocusMode(
                                Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                        // set picture format to JPEG, everytime makesure JPEg
                        globalCamera.getParameters().setPictureFormat(
                                ImageFormat.JPEG);
                        autoFocusSetupForBarcode(globalCamera);
                        /*
                         * START early setup variables & setting used in
                         * jpegCallback in order to optimize the jpegCallback code
                         */
                        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        // option set for down sampling he captured image taken from
                        // the camera in order to MemoryOutOfBounds exception
                        options.inSampleSize = 4;
                        // image quality rather than speed in order to achieve early
                        // barcode detection & decode
                        options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = false;
                        // Samsung galaxy S only , rotate to correct orientation
                        // ,and capture only the image within the guidance rectangle

                        rotationMatrix90CounterClockWise = new Matrix();
                        rotationMatrix90CounterClockWise.postRotate(90);
                        // early variable used by zxing to decode method
                        decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
                        decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
                        decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);
                        decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.ASSUME_CODE_39_CHECK_DIGIT,
                                Boolean.TRUE);
                        reader = new MultiFormatReader();

                        turnOnFlashlight(globalCamera);

                        // pass surfaceView to CameraPreview
                        newCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, globalCamera) {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                                        " onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) ");

                                onTouchEvent = true;
                                globalCamera
                                        .autoFocus(autoFocusCallbackForAutomaticScan);

                                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                            }

                        };

                        // pass CameraPreview to Layout
                        RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner.addView(newCameraPreview);


                        // give reference SurfaceView to camera object
                        globalCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceViewBarcodeScanner
                                .getHolder());

                        // PREVIEW
                        if (cameraPreviewing != true) {
                            globalCamera.startPreview();
                        }

                        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                                "camera opened & previewing");
                    }
                }// end else ,check for front camera
            }// end try
            catch (Exception exc) {

                // in case of exception release resources & cleanup
                if (globalCamera != null) {
                    globalCamera.stopPreview();
                    cameraPreviewing = false;
                    globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    globalCamera.release();
                    globalCamera = null;
                    options = null;
                    rotationMatrix90CounterClockWise = null;
                    reader = null;

                }
                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity initializeGlobalCamera() exception:",
                        exc.getMessage());
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }// end catch

        }// end ini

        /* this method detect whether the camera flashlight a.k.a torch feature is available to be turned on then turns on the light*/
        public void turnOnFlashlight(Camera camera) {
            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                    "turnOnFlashlight(Camera camera )");

            boolean flag = false;
            Context context  = null; 
            if (camera != null) {
                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                        "turnOnFlashlight() , FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH: " + flag);

                context = RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner.getContext();
                if (context != null) {
                    flag = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
                    if (flag) {
                        Flash = camera.getParameters();
                        Flash.setFlashMode("torch");

                        camera.setParameters(Flash);

                    }// end if camera feature is available

                    else {
                        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                                "turnOnFlashlight() , FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH: "
                                        + flag);
                    }
                }// end if context not null

            }// end camera not null

        }// end turnOnFlashlight(Camera camera )

        // onCreate, instantiates layouts & surfaceView used for video preview
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_vin_scanner);
            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity", "onCreate ");

            // create surfaceView for previewing of camera image
            RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutForPreview);
            surfaceViewBarcodeScanner = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewBarcodeScanner);
            barcodeVinScannerToolbar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutToolbar);



            initializeGlobalCamera();


            //*****TOOLBAR IS ADDED*****

            if (RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner!=null && barcodeVinScannerToolbar!=null)
            {

                //surfaceViewBarcodeScanner.addChildrenForAccessibility(list);
               RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner.addView(barcodeVinScannerToolbar);      

            }


            // instantiate orientationEventListener
            orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

                @Override
                public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {


                    /*
                    latestScreenOrientation = ScreenUtility
                            .getScreenOrientation(RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner.getContext());

                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                            "latestScreenOrientation: " + latestScreenOrientation);

                    if (orientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
                        orientationEventListener.enable();
                        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                                "enabled orientationEventListener: "
                                        + String.valueOf(orientationEventListener
                                                .canDetectOrientation()));
                    } else {
                        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                                "enabled orientationEventListener: "
                                        + String.valueOf(orientationEventListener
                                                .canDetectOrientation()));
                    }
    */
                }

            };



            handler = new Handler();




        }// end onCreate


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {

            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity, onResume() globalCamera:",
                    String.valueOf(globalCamera));

            initializeGlobalCamera();


            //*****TOOLBAR IS ADDED*****

            if (RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner!=null && barcodeVinScannerToolbar!=null)
            {

                //surfaceViewBarcodeScanner.addChildrenForAccessibility(list);
               RelativeLayoutBarcodeScanner.addView(barcodeVinScannerToolbar);      

            }


            if (orientationEventListener != null) {
                orientationEventListener.enable();
            }

            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {

            if (globalCamera != null) {
                globalCamera.stopPreview();
                cameraPreviewing = false;
                globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                globalCamera.release();
                globalCamera = null;
            }

            if (orientationEventListener != null) {
                orientationEventListener.disable();
            }
            super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            if (globalCamera != null) {
                globalCamera.stopPreview();
                cameraPreviewing = false;
                globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                globalCamera.release();
                globalCamera = null;
                options = null;
                rotationMatrix90CounterClockWise = null;
                reader = null;
            }
            if (orientationEventListener != null) {
                orientationEventListener.disable();
            }
            super.onPause();
        }// end onPause()

    //other irrelevant code was not included

    }//end activity
```

**Attempt #3, result, screen freezes , no particular error or exception reported:**

[image]

Error log:

[image]

**If the eclipse GUI tool shows the desired look , than why is the toolbar still missing??? I would like to have the toolbar in the bottom , preferably using RelativeLayout without any crashes or screen freezes. Any help will be appreciated.

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3 for testing.

Thanks.**

Comment: I am pretty sure your layout is right, I just tested it same on my end and works fine for me. I just used code from here :https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java                                              Have a look at the the screenshot :  http://goo.gl/8Z7oNU

Comment: You have a problem probably in the Activity code.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted something like this?

[image]

the layout I used is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please note that, since I didn't have **your images** in my res/drawable folder, I replaced them with **ic_launcher**.
Also note that I used an **ldpi** device running **Froyo** (API level 2.2). This is why the image is smaller than yours and the UI differs slighthly (...). Anyway, **it works at every resolution and with every os version**.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `LinearLayout` containing `imageView`

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: I added the property you mentioned but still no difference, I posted the new xml above.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is not to use a Relativelayout but instead use a Linearlayout as your root. Then set the surfaceview weight to 1, something like:

```
 <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I added the weight of 1 but it made no difference, also I rather keep it RelativeLayout, although I tried Linear and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell the `surfaceView` to be `above` the `linearLayout`.  Your code will need to look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ,I edited my layout & upload the new layout , however still no difference, the toolbar does not show.

Comment: Try to define your linearLayoutToolbar before the surfaceview, like my example.

Comment: I think this one looks correct.  I was going to suggest adding the surfaceview after the LinearLayout (instead of before, like in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use RelativeLayout as a root layout, I think it is much simplier to use LinearLayou with layout_weight parameter in one of children view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<SurfaceView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<!--  LinearLayout that contains toolbar that is divided into 3 sections horizontally -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the layout to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LayoutForPreview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.68"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few mistakes in your initial XML
1. In the surfaceview you use:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
```

You should use @+id when you create an Id but when you want to make a reference you should only do @id like this:

```
android:layout_above="@id/linearLayoutToolbar"
```

2. You can't do a reference to another object that isn't created yet! So you should put the surfaceview below de linearlayout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LayoutForPreview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.68"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
</LinearLayout>

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayoutToolbar"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

3. You should add weight to your 3 ImageViews like this:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some small changes in your initial layout will lead to remove the error.  You need to use `android:layout_height="0dp"` , defining 0dp will help your surfaceview to fit in your screen.

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
    />
```

And I've not found use of below attribute in SurfaceView.

```
    android:layout_gravity="top" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Checkout this layout designs, how [android:layout_height="0dp"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Example) works, and how [android:layout_width="0dp"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Example) works.

Answer (score 0):

I have used that kind of layouts in many apps, and here is how should be your layout. No tricks, no praying for luck, this is just the clean,  happy, and always-working way to achieve it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.68"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[here you have a preview on one of my apps.](https://lh6.ggpht.com/zWeOy9FU5EcQ1ELaW1UE8V72QCN5Ok02FQIV1bvVXK6YDODrrU5ge9eDNi4tSrh3Gw=h900-rw)

The posted code is adapted to yours so a copy/paste will do it. please note that its everything in a simple file, so you have to change slightly your activity